# Best way to store user's input in a multi-step application

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard

My program consists of a number of steps. Say each step is in a `tabpage` on which upon completion, the user selects "Next". 
What is the best/fastest way of storing these information?

Comment: What are the requirements? What do you mean with 'storing'?

Comment: Difficult to say without understanding more, but I'd say as a global complex type "UserData" or something. But if you need to save this data in case someone comes back later, it might be more complex..

Comment: What kind of information you wanna store?

Comment: @L-Three No special requirements. No I just need to save this information as long as the program runs. So let's say it's something like filling an online application that will be gone once it's canceled or the browser is closed.

Comment: @manuchao normal form data, the user is supposed to run a campaign: so the first step s/he chooses a file of subscribers, step two, the type of campaign is chosen and third campaign, based on the type a different form is shown so the user can fill campaign information and then run it. step 4, looks like an overall review of everything the user has set and then "Run".

Answer (score 1):

I would generally say that this would be one Model to keep all the data - which then gets forwarded to the processing method once the user says "ok" at the last page. BUt then this depends a lot on actual usage scenarios, so that may not be the best way all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate class that had properties for the 'answers' on the individual pages.  Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it worked perfectly for me.  The user could go back and forth between the pages and the answers were stored.  To Prescott's point, if they need to come back later perhaps you could save their partial form out as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Create a viewmodel that represents the wizard, and in that viewmodel all the data related to your steps. You can also keep track of current step, and implement some methods to enable/disable next and previous buttons etc.

Your actual wizard window and tabs (the views) then all work with the wizard viewmodel (the data).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with In-Memory Repository if you just want to retain this information for program execution, For example

```
namespace Repository {
    public class InMemoryRepository : IRepository{
        static readonly List<Item> items = new List<Item> {
            new Item("CurrentTaxRate", 20m),
            new Item("CurrentAmount", 100m)
        };
        public Item Get(string name) {
            return items.Single(x => x.Name == name);
        }
    }
}

public class Item {
    public Item(string name, decimal value) {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }
}
```

You can bolt on Add, Delete or Edit functionality easily to this and replace the "Item" here with your own "UserData" type.

Use dependency injection for getting this information back

```
    public class TaxRate : ITaxRate {
        private readonly IRepository repository;

        public TaxRate(IRepository repository) {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public decimal Get() {
            var item = repository.Get("CurrentTaxRate");
            return item.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: THat is super weak because you miss out on any databinding and integral testing logic to validate the parameters - something you can do in a properlty strong typed viewmodel.

Comment: I agree to what you say about databinding etc but at no point the question states that this needs to be in database in fact questioner has specifically stated in comments that they want to retain data till program execution only so this in-memory repository is just a temporary datastore as demanded by questioner.

Comment: And where does a viewmodel (i.e. a class) go into the database automatically? Get real. DataBinding has nothing to do with Database. But if you go proper form architecture you start having this thing around called a "Model". It has nothing to do with a database.